# Upload file to MySQL only 6MB?

Tags: php, mysql, upload, size

I've been using PHP upload file into MySQL database.
But I noticed that I can only upload files not exceeding 6MB.

How can I increase the upload size? Up to what size am I able to upload file?

Below is my PHP file.

**index.php**

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","Localhost"," ");
    mysql_select_db("uploadfile");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
        $url = "http://127.0.0.1/file/uploaded/$name";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `file` VALUE ('','$name','$url')");
    }

    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="file.php">Show File</a>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!" />
    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "<br />".$name." has been uploaded";
    }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**file.php**

```
  <?php

    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","Localhost"," ");
    mysql_select_db("uploadfile");

    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `file`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br />";
    }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring your php.ini file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: People don't even bother to search a bit before asking...

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php.ini with these value.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. 
upload_max_filesize = 40M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize 
post_max_size = 40M
```

I think this question is already answered here: [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use this

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

This will set the max filesize to 10 Megabytes you can ofcourse change the number to your liking

This is where i found the answer awhile ago myself:
[Upload large files](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your **php.ini** file which can be found by opening your **Control Panel**. Click *Config* of your Apache, and select `PHP (php.ini)`. Search for the keyword `upload_max_filesize=`. You can change the *max file size* in your system. Save and close. If still didn't work. Try restarting your **Apache**.

Your **second option** is having `($_FILES["file"]["size"]<$uploadsize)` on your upload condition. Just change the `$uploadsize` variable to your preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure php.ini. The values should changed as follows:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 8MB

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 8MB
```

The default as in your case may be set to 2MB, if I am not wrong. The following link will give you a clear picture.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php